# UL-LI sub-menu appears when my mouse goes over the place where it has to appear.

Tags: html, css

Sorry for my bad english. After hours of tries, my UL/LI sub-menu finaly appears with a transition, but now i've got a problem. When my moes goes under the button, the sub-menu appears.

-> here's the fiddle, only the red button has a sub-menu. To see the problem, put your mouse way bellow the red button.

http://jsfiddle.net/AXLgx/2/

Here's the code :

```
    nav
    {
        height: 71px;
        width:1106px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    #horizontalmenu ul {
        padding:0px; 
        margin: 0px;
        list-style:none;
    }

    #horizontalmenu li {
        float:left; 
        width: 90px;
        height: 55px;
        position:relative; 

        display: inline-block;


        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #horizontalmenu li ul {
        width: 88px;
        padding:0px; 
        margin: 0px;
        opacity: 0;
        /*display:none;*/
        position:absolute;
        background:gray;
        border-left: 1px #2a2a2a solid; 
        border-right: 1px #2a2a2a solid; 
        border-bottom: 1px #2a2a2a solid; 
        transition: all .6s;

    }

    #horizontalmenu li:hover ul {



        display:block;
        width: 88px;
        height:auto; 
        /*width:90px;*/

        opacity: 0.9;



    }       




    #horizontalmenu li ul li{

        float: none; 
        position: static; 
        height: 40px; 
        line-height: 40px; 
        background: none; 
        padding: 2px;
        clear:both;
        text-align: center;
        width:88px;




    }
    #horizontalmenu li ul li a{


        /*display: block; PTET ICI */

        height: 40px; 
        font-size:12px;

        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        width:88px;



    }

    #horizontalmenu li:hover ul li { 

        width:88px;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 2px;
        height: 40px; 
        line-height: 40px; 
        border-bottom: 2px #9f9f9f dotted;
        text-align: center;


    }

    #horizontalmenu li ul li:hover {

        background: #2a2a2a;

    }

    #horizontalmenu li ul li:hover a
    {

        position: static;
        height: 40px;
        display: inline-block;

    }

HTML 

<nav align="center">
    <span class="milieunav"><div class="horizontalmenu" id="horizontalmenu"><!--

    --><ul class="ulnav" id="menu"><li>

    <a href="#" class="b-accueil"></a></li><li class="libook">
        <a href="#" class="b-book"></a><!--
            --><ul class="sub-menu"><!--
                --><li><a href="#">Introduction</a></li><!--
                --><li><a href="#">Devenir Spades</a></li><!--
                --><li><a href="#">Regles et lois</a></li><!--
                --><li><a href="#">Grades</a></li><!--
                --><li><a href="#">Histoire</a></li><!--
            --></ul><!--
            --></li><li>
        <a href="#" class="b-commun"></a>
        </li><li>
        <a href="#" class="b-activite"></a>
        </li><li>
        <a href="#" class="b-bigben"></a>
        </li><li>
        <a href="#" class="b-bulle"></a>
        </li></ul><!--

    --></div></span><!--








    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element is still there, just 100% transparent. You have to remove it from the layout with `display: none` instead of making it invisible with `opacity`.

EDIT: You mention transitions, so I take it you want the menu to fade in and out. For this purpose `display: none` might not be the way to go since it can prevent opacity to animate.

Consider `visibility` which can be animated, unlike `display`. When going this route, use `visibility` and `opacity`. The first one to prevent the elements from receiving events such as hover, and the later for the visual effect.

Do keep in mind that for the fade out you need to give a delay for the transition of the `visibility` otherwise the menu will go invisible right away (it animates from 0 to 1, with no values in-between). The fade-out transitions are set on the non-hover rule.

one tutorial can be seen here: http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337

see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-shorthand-property to know how to specify different transition parameters for different properties.

Comment: This tutorial is awesome ! Thanks a lot :)